# Perform date range query from a single column control table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

Let's say I have the following tables

**tableA**

```
seq datea
1   2010-01-01
2   2010-02-01
3   2010-03-01
```

**tableb**

```
dateb      sthvalue
2010-01-11 AAA
2010-01-12 AAB
2010-02-03 CCC
2010-02-06 CCD
2010-02-10 CCE
2010-03-05 FFF
```

I want to join the two tables on `tableb.dateb` is within the daterange of `tablea`

i.e. output should be

```
seq datea      dateb      sthvalue
1   2010-01-01 2010-01-11 AAA
1   2010-01-01 2010-01-12 AAB
2   2010-02-01 2010-02-03 CCC
2   2010-02-01 2010-02-06 CCD
2   2010-02-01 2010-02-10 CCE
3   2010-03-01 2010-03-05 FFF
```

Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "range" the same month, year, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that table A values are always one month apart and set on the 1st of each month, the existing answers will do.

If your table A can contain more variety:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableB b
       inner join
    TableA a
       on
          b.dateb >= a.datea
       left join
    TableA a_nolater
       on
          a_nolater.datea > a.datea and
          b.dateb >= a_nolater.datea
WHERE
    a_nolater.seq is null
```

This joins the two tables together, then attempts to find a "better" join (a row from tablea that occurs later than the currently matching one, and would still be a match for tableb). It only returns rows where it cannot find this "better" join. As such, it find the latest dated row in tableA that is on or before the date from tableB.

Comment: Thanks your so much for the answer! but i must join the table in the seq tableA then tableB, as the tableA is the a monthly statement and tableB is statement transaction. i'll try work out how should i do that. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking for is to join on year and month

```
select 
      seq,datea,dateb,sthvalue 
from 
      TableA inner join Tableb 
      on datepart(year,datea) = datepart(year,dateb) and 
         datepart(month,datea) = datepart(month,dateb)
      order by seq,dateb
```

Comment: oh, the date is not guarantee to be monthly. i've post a misleading example

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
select
    a.seq,
    a.datea,
    b.dateb,
    b.sthvalue
from 
    tablea a inner join tableb b on (b.dateb >= a.datea and b.dateb < dateadd(month, 1, a.datea))
order by 
    a.seq, b.sthvalue
```

Comment: oh, the date is not guarantee to be monthly. i've post a misleading example.